# How to automate log in to SAP Business Objects

Tags: c#, python, node.js, download, automation

I'm trying to automate a file download process of spreadsheets (.xls files) kept in a **SAP Business Objects** server. Here's the process:

1. User logs into SAP Business Objects.
2. User selects report from a list of reports.
3. Once the report has opened the user triggers the download from another link.

Here is how I originally planned to attack this:

1. Send a post request to the server providing login credentials.
2. Process response back from server to save session/cookie information.
3. Send a get request to the server with the static link used to trigger the download.

   - This request that is sent must go through one or two forwarders because viewing this request in wireshark reveals that the request that *actually* triggers the download is different from the one that initiates the download. The request that triggers the download contains counters and other parameters that I can not duplicate unless I try finding the pattern.
4. Save the download response to a file.

Is there a tutorial out there for this sort of process? I'm looking to write this in C# but if there's something better, Python, NodeJS, anything, I'm all ears.

I'm imagining this is something simple like sending requests and processing responses but how do I handle receiving multiple responses? Would the best way to troubleshoot/debug something like this be to use Wireshark so I could watch the data requests fly back and forth between my machine and the server?

Comment: There are tutorials about making HTTP requests in virtually every language - so that is indeed possible in C#, Python, NodeJS, etc. I'm not sure about SAP Business Objects, or if what you describe (POST'ing, GET'ing a download) makes sense for that.

Comment: I might be able to dump Wireshark logs if that is of help.

Comment: this question is too broad - are you having a particular problem with some specific code?

Comment: No, not in particular. But I get confused as to why when I send a request I get multiple responses. Is that a result of the primary .jsp/.html file being returned which then sources *it's* dependencies like scripts, images, etc..?

Comment: when retrieving a web page (for example, hitting refresh here), the page loads everything asynchronously - so yes many different requests for all the images and .js files. Usually in a specific API request, you'll receive just 1 response from the server. http://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/